# How to increase progress view in iPhone, till the response coming from server in the form of JSON

Tags: iphone

I am new in iPhone development and want to add progress view in my application, can somebody help me out how I can add progress view in my iPhone application, and how this progress view will increase gradually when server response coming in the form of json.

Comment: what are you using to get the server response?

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code from the use of mbprogesshud ,hope u can set the progress of your progressview also by this method.refer to the nsurldelegate methods how they are setting the progress according to the data coming from the server

```
  - (IBAction)showWIthLabelAnnularDeterminate:(id)sender {
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

        // Set determinate mode
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;

        HUD.delegate = self;
        HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

        // myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    }



    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegete

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        expectedLength = [response expectedContentLength];
        currentLength = 0;
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        currentLength += [data length];
        HUD.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
        [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        [HUD hide:YES];
    }
```